# Called method dynamic way

Tags: java

I have one class which contains 100 get methods.

For example :

```
public class ResponsseDetails {
    public String getResponse2() {
        return response2;
      }
      public String getResponse3() {
        return response3;
      }
      public String getResponse4() {
        return response4;
      }
      public String getResponse5() {
        return response5;
      }
      public String getResponse6() {
        return response6;
      }
      public String getResponse7() {
        return response7;
      }

    .....
    .....

    public String getResponse100() {
            return response100;
          }
}
```

Now I am trying get those variable in for loop by following way :

```
ResponseDetails responseDetails = new ResponseDetails();

for(SetWiseQuesDetailTable setDetails : result_2) {
          if (setDetails.getQa() != null) {
            if (setDetails.getQa().equals(responseDetails.getResponse1())) {
              ansDetailsList.add("V");
            }
            if (setDetails.getQa().equals(responseDetails.getResponse2())) {
              ansDetailsList.add("V");
            }
            ......
            ......
            if (setDetails.getQa().equals(responseDetails.getResponse100())) {
                  ansDetailsList.add("V");
            }

          }
}
```

In the above code I wrote `100 if - else` to get 100 methods which is very long process. Is there any other best way to implement the above code?

Comment: The usual way would be to not put 100 methods in a class. You could have an array of 100 different implementations of `Supplier<String>`. Or you could have one method and pass it a number between 1 and a hundred.

Comment: Is it not possible to restructure this so you have `String[] responses`? You can do it with reflection but it would just be better to reconstruct your code.

Comment: Looks like you could use a HashMap or similar data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a `HashMap`

```
HashMap<String,String> hashmap = new HashMap();
hashmap.put("response1","key1");
hashmap.put("response2","key2");
//Add upto 100 key value pairs as per your requirement
```

Now you can get the value of hashmap like this;

```
String key = setDetails.getQa();

if(key != null) {
 if(hashmap.containsKey(key)){

    String value = (String) hashmap.get(key);
     ansDetailsList.add(value);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection for this. There's a neat library called [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) that you could do something like this:

```
Set<Method> methods = ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods(ResponseDetails.class, ReflectionUtils.withPrefix("getResponse"),
                                                        ReflectionUtils.withParametersCount(0), ReflectionUtils.withReturnType(String.class));

    for(SetWiseQuesDetailTable setDetails : result_2) {
        for (Method method : methods) {
            String response = (String) method.invoke(responseDetails);
            if (setDetails.getQA().equals(response)) {
                ansDetailsList.add("V");
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically ReflectionUtils allows you to get all the "getResponse" like methods and then iterate over them invoking them through reflection and comparing them to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the strings to be publicly available? (You are using `public` methods, that is why I am asking). If you do not, the following code might be better/clearer:

```
for(SetWiseQuesDetailTable setDetails : result_2) {
      // this prevents calling the function getQa() over and over again
      String qa = setDetails.getQa();
      if (qa != null) {
        switch (qa) {
          case "response1" : 
              // do your stuff here
              break; // you shouldn't forget this one here
          [...]
          case "response1000": // procced as above
        }
     }
}
```

Using a switch (see e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)) captures your idea of a 100-fold decision pretty well. Note that this will prevent the responses the be seen from outside the class. That might be an issue.

When looking at code "cleanliness" you should go for 
[Anshul Jain's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35138095/5848786) solution as this will not only make your code more easily adaptive (you can dynamically add or remove responses from your "database") it also improves readability (only one place to look for what is happening) and removes error sources. This is an issue as you copy your code 100 times. If you need to change something, you need to change it in 99 other places as well. This may lead to mistakes by forgetting a single case or simple mispelling errors.